# current_page_item and custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, navigation, wp-list-pages

I have a page on my site that lists all posts for my custom post type 'Literature'.

However when I click on one of the posts, the highlighted active menu item changes to 'Blog'.

How do I assign these posts to the menu item 'Literature'?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use wordpress's built in menu manager for this, along with a specific template file for listing the custom post types (for instance template-literature.php).

Comment: my pleasure! did it work for you?